# How do I navigate to a different route in my react application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to create new Routes for my works web application, but the way that they are using the Routes is not the way I thought they would be used.  Essentially I want to add new routes and be able to click on say like a button, and that will take me to the desired route that I want to go to.

The way it is set up in our application is that you actually have to manually go in the browser and type in the extended path to access that route, which doesn't seem like a good way of doing it.

Right now I have a route set up for our inventory system.  You would access this route by typing in *localhost::3000/inventory*.  There are buttons that come up on this main page which when clicked render that specific component.  Instead of doing it that way, I would rather set up another route like */additem* to the inventory path so that when I click on the *Add Item* button it will take me to the path *localhost::3000/inventory/additem* and render that component.

This is what our index.js file looks like for reference

```
import "babel-polyfill";
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/fn/array/find';
import 'core-js/fn/array/includes';
import 'core-js/fn/number/is-nan';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

import ServiceReport from './imports/ServiceReportUI/ServiceReport'
import './StyleSheets/ServiceReport.css';
import InventorySystem from './imports/InventorySystem/InventorySystem.js';
import AddNewItemBtn from "./imports/InventorySystem/AddNewItemBtn";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom' 

ReactDOM.render((
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={App}/>
            <Route path='/service' component={ServiceReport} />
            <Route exact path='/inventory' component={InventorySystem} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>), document.getElementById('appRoot'));
```

I'm thinking that adding another route like so will do the trick:

```
<Route exact path='/inventory/additem' component={AddItem} />
```

And I would access that route from within my InventorySystem.js file by doing something like this:

```
Class InventorySystem extends React.Component{
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {}
 }

 goTo(e){
  //go to Add Item path
 }

 render(){
  return(
  <button onClick={this.goTo.bind(this)}>Add Item</button>

  )

 }
}
```

I don't know much about React Router, and I'm also not sure if this is the right way of going about this, but any help or suggestions would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to navigate within a React-Router setup is by using the `Link` component provided by the repo. Your first suggestion to create an additional Route for the `AddItem` component is correct. Simply import the `Link` component and define the expected path to go to.

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom

class InventorySystem extends React.Component{
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {}
 }

 render(){
  return(
     <Link to="/addItem">Add Item</Link>
  )
 }
}
```

You can style the `Link` to look like a button if needed as it does accept a className property.

Comment: Ok that seems simple enough.  Is it possible to wrap the Link component in a button tag like this? <button><Link to="/addItem">Add Item</Link></button>  Or will this not work?

Comment: @Michael yup you could, and the reverse is possible as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options, both included in example below

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class InventorySystem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
  }

  goTo(e) {
    // option 1
    this.props.history.push('/inventory/additem');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.goTo.bind(this)}>Add Item</button> // option 1
        <Link to="/inventory/additem">Add Item</Link> // option 2
      </div>
    )

  }
}
```